# Inkscape: How can I bend text like in this example?

Tags: inkscape

I tried several Path Effects, but I never were able to get text looking like this:
[image]

As you can see, the text goes slightly upwards, and the letters get smaller. I first thought Envelope deformation would make this easy, just aligning the envelope paths to the top and bottom border of the original text; but it ended up stretching the letters like rubber:

[image]

The letters are bend vertically, which I do not want. Also, I seem to get problems with my outline and gradient which I couldn't even fix. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely achieve this with "Envelope Deformation". I think you were almost there, but ignored a slight rotation in the original. If you rotate the original by roughly 15° (clockwise), then model your envelope and finally rotate your object back, you should be fine.

*Here's what I got:*

[image]

*Steps to follow in Inkscape:*

1. **Pick a good font**. I think for the final look this is more important than anything else. I chose [BadaBoom BB](http://www.dafont.com/badaboom-bb.font). **Add the desired text** (e.g. "GROAR") *in normal orientation*.
2. **Style the text** (black 5px stroke, vertical three-point gradient spanning the entire line height).
3. **Do the envelope deformation**. At this point you have to convert the text to a path, which is a bit of a pity, as you lose editability. Bend the top and bottom paths like so:
   [image]

*Note:* You can play with the spline nodes in each path to increase the "turning effect" of the letters. Sometimes, the outline of the deformed object may react in "funky ways" (like you mentioned), however, with a bit of node tweaking and moving you should be able to find a constellation in which everything looks proper.

4. **Rotate your object** counter-clockwise by 15°.
5. (Optional) **Add the comic shadow effect** from the original.

*A final suggestion*: If you want to produce a lot of text objects with this effect (e.g. to illustrate a cartoon), you may want to use "Put on Path" (from the "Text" menu) instead of "Envelope Deformation". It will produce the same turning effect (no scaling/deformation, though) and keep your text editable.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to type out your word, ad a gradient fill, a black stroke ad a slight warp (arch) to it and then use the sheer tool in illustrator to make it rise more closely to your reference image. Below is a screenshot of how I did my settings for the Arch Warp.

[image]

Comment: Make sure to expand your type to outlines as well.

Comment: HI Andrew Mark Beauman, thank you for submitting an answer. Your method was done in Illustrator and OP is asking how to do this in the program [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) which I don't think has these options.